# MVC multiple jquery.ajax waiting one after another

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Ok, so I have multiple $.ajax in my view. All of them link to the same Controller/Action (but with varying param values).

```
$("#div1").load(url + "?myParam=1");
$("#div2").load(url + "?myParam=2");
```

Of course, I did that so that they would load independently, for a better load time.

Here's my controller Action:

```
public PartialViewResult MyAction(int myParam){
var reader = new Reader(this.ConnectionString);
string output;
switch (myParam)
{
case 1:
    Thread.Sleep(15000);
    output = reader.Get("One");
case 2:
    output = reader.Get("Two")
}
}
```

See that Thread.Sleep over there?
Well, I was expecting that the second div would load instantly, but guess what, it waits for the first one to finish.

the reader does some EntityFramework Stuff

```
public string Get(string input){
 using var ctx = new Entities();
 
 return ctx.Something.Where(s => s.Whatever == input).Id;
}
```

Comment: This is because the server limits the number of concurrent connections per client, to prevent attacks such as DDOS. This is why it's always better to send a single AJAX request which returns all necessary information, instead of sending lots of AJAX requests with more granular detail. Also, just to be clear as I'm sure this was just testing, using `Thread.Sleep()` on a webserver is incredibly bad practice.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little, please? What is the default value, where I can change it from? I doubt though, that the default setting is 1 connection per client. I have this issue both on IIS (published) and IIS Express (dev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the session. Session access is sequentially for the same user. Would need to decorate actions with **[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]** (but they won't have access to Session)

*Access to ASP.NET session state is exclusive per session, which means that if two different users make concurrent requests, access to each separate session is granted concurrently. However, if two concurrent requests are made for the same session (by using the same SessionID value), the first request gets exclusive access to the session information. The second request executes only after the first request is finished.*

Comment: It seems that this issue no longer exists in ASP.NET Core ‍♀️